# ERR unknown command 'FT._LIST' .Net Core project

Tags: docker, .net-core, redis-stack

I'm using and installed the latest version of RedisStack with docker, everything was Ok, but suddenly I couldn't run the project and when I run the project the exception raised and it says
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: 'ERR unknown command 'FT._LIST''
but when I run the command in Redis-cli in docker, it returns the data.
I reinstall the Redis-Stack container, but it doesn't work.
my Redis port is localhost:6379
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may well be that you have another instance of the Redis Server process running on port 6379 outside your Docker container and that's what your code is connecting to.  If so then it looks like that instance of Redis isn't Redis Stack as it doesn't have the Search capability installed.

Check your running processes to see if other instances of `redis-server` exist and kill them before starting your Docker container.  Also make sure your Redis Stack Docker container is forwarding port 6379 to your host.

Comment: that's right, I forgot to install a Redis MSI installer in windows and run a Redis windows service on services, after I stop the service, it's worked.
thank you very much